# A word meaning to dig land with your nails or fingers

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

What do you call "to dig land" with fingers? If I say “He desperately dug the soil” it sounds like the person is using a tool such as a shovel or a spade. Which verb means digging with *only* your fingers or fingernails?

> He desperately _______ the soil.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how you would like to use this word?

Comment: Nobody has mentioned "grub" or "root". To "grub" or to "root" both convey the idea of digging by hand, or by claw.

Comment: @sumelic Seriously, how difficult is it to imagine a sentence using that particular word? Agreed, often users who pose their question do not provide any context, but in this case the request is as clear as a bell. There is no confusion. Now if the OP wants to, he can  modify the example I've provided, and perhaps explain "why" he needs this word.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Comments from the OP: "Here is needed a word to dig anything with fingers to get lost something in the something exactly as rabbits dig to make thier houses to live!" "I don't know why this question's been edited 'Look up' means to find word in the dictionary and 'Look for' to search somethig. some pleople are showing their talents here while they don't know what dose mean 'to look up" The first comment is quite confusing to me, but I thought it may mean there are more specific requirements for the word...

Comment: The second comment suggests to me that the OP may not understand the meaning of all the edits to the question. Now that it's been edited more, I have voted to re-open, but I'm still not sure if the current version of the question accurately reflects the original intended question.

Comment: @sumelic The OP didn't understand why "look up" was edited to "look for", the editor/user/deadrat was correct, but I don't think it adds nothing of value to the question itself. The OP wants us to look up a word that he is looking for.  The word he is looking for is "to dig with fingers", the edited question still has that request. I added a reason as to why "dig" by itself is not sufficient, and provided an example sentence. The question is essentially unchanged from the original.

Answer (score 4):

**Scrabble**

> Scratch or grope around with one's fingers to find, collect, or hold
>   onto something. "She scrabbled at the grassy slope, desperate for a
>   firm grip."

[Google definition](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20scrabble)

> Now, she was famished, and had a fantasy of reaching down to scrabble
>   for roots, like Scarlett O'Hara in Gone With the Wind. For more than
>   an hour, she and ...

The Perennial Killer: A Gardening Mystery by Ann Ripley

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I was wondering how to cite google.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the following verbs:

- [paw](http://www.aamboli.com/translate/paw)
- [claw](http://www.aamboli.com/translate/claw)
- [burrow](http://www.aamboli.com/translate/burrow)

You could look for narrower synonyms also called hyponyms for a word.
I used [dig](http://www.aamboli.com/translate/dig) to find narrower synonyms which are avaliable for most of the words on [www.aamboli.com](http://www.aamboli.com/)

Comment: The website you mention seems to use other sources (eg Farlex) without attribution, which may well be infringing copyright rules. And though there is some useful material, it is confusingly presented.

Comment: The data is from an open source technology (Wordnet) and not from Farlex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a word for "digging land with your fingers". If I were to put it in context, I would say, "I began digging into the ground with my hands."
Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Given that isn't, so be it! God has given us 10 fingers of hands. Here is needed a word to dig anything with fingers to get lost something in the something exactly as rabbits dig to make thier houses to live!

Comment: I don't know why this question's been edited "Look up" means to find word in the dictionary and "Look for" to search somethig. some pleople are showing their talents here while they don't know what dose mean 'to look up

Comment: deadrat isn't wrong. Starting a sentence with 'looking up' makes the sentence a statement of fact, meaning that you are currently looking something up. Looking for means you are actually trying to find the word.

Comment: 'I don't think there's a word for ...' almost always belongs in a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for next time. Shall I delete my post, then?